# Angular component for radio buttons isn't binding correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom angular component which contains some html to build a radio form control. This component is passed a number of properties from the parent component, which are then used to populate the properties on the radio itself.

However, the radio doesn't perform as a group, each one can be selected independently, and the radio buttons themselves appear to load one by one on the page as if it is hanging when rendering them.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ceehgd

```
<!-- parent component -->
<app-radio-control
  [id]="'appointmentReason1'"
  [formControlName]="'appointmentReason'"
  [radioValue]="1"
  [label]="'Mortgage'"
></app-radio-control>

<app-radio-control
  [id]="'appointmentReason2'"
  [formControlName]="'appointmentReason'"
  [radioValue]="2"
  [label]="'Protection'"
></app-radio-control>

<app-radio-control
  [id]="'appointmentReason3'"
  [formControlName]="'appointmentReason'"
  [radioValue]="3"
  [label]="'Mortgage & Protection'"
></app-radio-control>


<!-- radio component -->
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input
    formControlName="{{ formControlName }}"
    name="{{ formControlName }}"
    class="custom-control-input"
    type="radio"
    id="{{ id }}"
    [value]="radioValue"
    required
  />
  <label for="{{ id }}" class="custom-control-label">{{ label }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @MikeS. Sure, added to the question

Comment: @SamWillis ,  check this sample maybe help you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-radio-button

Comment: I found a great article that makes your problem a little more clear https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html . In short, you will need to implement the `ControlValueAccesor` interface in your component to be able to use it as a custom form control.

Comment: @MikeS. Struggling to implement that and get it working

Comment: Made a few changes, maybe you'll have to tweak it a little bit still https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqcau4

Comment: @MikeS. looks great thanks